# How do you check for memory leaks in a ReactJS application that utilizes useCallback and useMemo?

Tags: reactjs, sockets

I have a data stream to subscribe to the script token, displaying the script price using sockets. However, a problem arises when the internet connection is lost and later restored. During this time, all script subscriptions are regained, and the prices are displayed again. At this point, my React webpage becomes unresponsive.

I have tried to manage all the script subscriptions on one page, which is causing the unresponsiveness issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.